# how to change font size of label without changing font family in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, xcode6

how to change font size of label without changing font family in xcode6 ?I am using following line of code:

```
lblMain.font =  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
```

Comment: suppose i change font to arial programmatically and then i want font size of 22 the this code set back the font family to system of size 22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
lblMain.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:22];
```

Or - you can even use the current font:

```
lblMain.font = [lblMain.font fontWithSize:22];
```

Comment: how can i get current font name in place of HelveticaNeue

Comment: Look at the second example I gave you. You can use the current font you already set.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *fontName = lblMain.font.fontName;
CGFloat fontSize = lblMain.font.pointSize;

[lblMain setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:NEWSIZE]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[lblMain setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17]];
```

Comment: you have used helveticaNeue as font name but in my case the scene is different. I have 6 buttons which changes font and 6 buttons which changes font size.If i change the font family and then i change the font size then i dont want to change font family i only want font size to be changed

Answer (score 1):

Use following code, if you just want to change font size keeping the same font family:

```
lblMain.font = [UIFont fontWithName:lblMain.font.fontName size:22.0f];
```

**OR**

You can also use this code:

```
lblMain.font = [lblMain.font fontWithSize:22.0f];
```